# Firestore - filter documents by date range?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to hold documents where one property is a 'scheduled' date field.  I want to retrieve a list of docs filtered by a start-finish date range on the 'scheduled' field.

A few tests on my side, and after reading the Google Firestore docs, suggests that Firestore does not support date range filtering. Is the correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do this using `where` query. For this to work you need to store your dates as unixtimestamp

```
.where("start_time":isGreaterThan,"1234567654").where("end_time":isLessThan, "23454323456")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does support date filtering. You just need to be careful how you store your dates.

Some people store dates as string, if you store as string with DD-MM-YYYY format, it will make your query invalid because 01-01-2023 < 02-01-2022.
But if you store it as a string YYYY-MM-DD, this won't be a problem.

I recommend that you store using the Data object, from firestore itself, you can filter in the following way.

```
const from = new Date("2023-01-01");
const today = new Date();
const q = query(citiesRef, where("created", "<=", today), where("created", ">=", from));
```

Or, you can save the dates as unix time, and filter as if they were 2 integers. Firestore is amazing, you can do a lot, it all depends on data modeling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **where** query from FirestoreCore package.

example:

`Timestamp from = Timestamp(1706316010); Timestamp today = Timestamp.now(); final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collection_name").where("createdAt", isGreaterThan: from).where("createdAt", isLessThan: today).get();"`;